# MySql triggers can't update same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Problem is that, I want a trigger that deletes old rows in the same table that the new rows are being inserted into.

`MsSQL` and `oracle` can do this, 
but looks like `mySQL` can't,

It allows the trigger to be created, but when it runs it gives the error

> "can't update table "tbl" in stored procedure or function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statemtent whicgh invoked this stored
>   procedure or function/trigger"

Any work around for this?
Is it planned in future releases?

Answer (score 0):

I have in my database all tables with filed name GHOST, so when GHOST is TRUE this row is like DELETED. So if You want change row after insert maybe use like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigg
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
SET NEW.ghost = TRUE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```